# values from text file not being written to 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I am attempting to take the values of a text file and load it into a 2D array. The problem I am running into is that the value of the char variable only seems to overwrite every position blank and I'm not sure why.

So I have the file open, I can access it to read it's contents or display them on the screen, and set up my 2D array like so:

```
    char chessBoards[BOARD_SIZE - 1][BOARD_SIZE - 1] = {{'A'}}; // All elements of 2D array initialized

    int x = 0; // line position - which line we are looking at
    int y = 0; // row position - which row we are looking at
```

Bit in this test the output is all C characters with a single D character where I later told it to be, so my problem seems to be that the positions of the text file are not being copied to the char variable.

```
file.open(games);
        char point = 'Z';
        while (file.get(point))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++)
            {

                for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
                {
                    chessBoards[x][y] = point;
                }
            }

        }

        chessBoards[1][1] = 'D';
        cout << chessBoards[1][1];


        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++)
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
            {
                cout << "chessBoards[" << x << "][" << y << "]: ";
                cout << chessBoards[x][y] << endl;
            }
        }
```

But in this variation every value is blank except for the one 'D'

```
file.open(games);
        char point = 'Z';
        while (file.get(point))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++)
            {

                for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
                {
                    chessBoards[x][y] = 'C';
                }
            }

        }
        cout << chessBoards[1][1];


        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++)
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
            {
                cout << "chessBoards[" << x << "][" << y << "]: ";
                cout << chessBoards[x][y] << endl;
            }
        }
```

Which tells me that it's not properly getting the values from the file to begin with, but in this version there is no problem displaying the contents of the file on top. However, if I try to put the other stuff in that same area it will only overwrite the first position of the array and stop.

```
    file.open(games);
    char point = 'Z';
    while (file.get(point))
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++)
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
            {
                chessBoards[x][y] = 'C';

            }

        }

        chessBoards[x][y] = 'C';
        chessBoards[x][y] = point;
        cout << point;

    }

    chessBoards[1][1] = 'D';
    cout << chessBoards[1][1];
```

Comment: the `x` and `y` variables that you declare outside the loops aren't the same as the ones declared inside the nested `for`s, their values remain `0`, so after the loops you are basically setting `chessBoards[0][0] = point;`. To actually read the file you should change the line in the loops to `chessBoards[x][y] = point`. Then listen to Paddy and declare the array as `chessBoard[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start here with two errors in one line:

```
char chessBoards[BOARD_SIZE - 1][BOARD_SIZE - 1] = {{'A'}};
```

First, you must use `BOARD_SIZE` (*not* `BOARD_SIZE-1`) for your dimension.  This will allow indexing between 0 and `BOARD_SIZE-1` inclusive.  You had undefined behaviour in your loops.

Since you have been writing off the end of the array, you could be trashing other variables in the stack, and anything could happen.  Declare the board like this:

```
char chessBoards[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
```

Second, that initialisation does *not* initialise every element to `'A'`.  It only initialises the first, and then zeros every other element.  You want something like `std::fill_n` (from `<algorithm>`):

```
std::fill_n( (char*)chessBoards, BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE, 'A' );
```

Or just `memset` (oldschool styles):

```
memset( chessboards, 'A', sizeof(chessBoards) );
```

Now the actual board reading.  You have been rewriting the entire board for every character.  That means when your `while` loop finally finishes, the board would contain the very last character that was read.  This is probably a new-line, and so later outputting the board it would appear empty.

Essentially, you're reading from the file in the wrong part of the loop.  Do this instead:

```
file.open( games );
if( file.is_open() )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < BOARD_SIZE; x++) 
    { 
        for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++) 
        { 
            char point = 'C'; 
            if( !file.get( point ) ) 
                std::cout << "Error reading " << x << "," << y << std::endl; 
            chessBoards[x][y] = point;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the BOARD_SIZE is not an error. I need a total of 8 positions in the array (0 through 7), but in another area of the program I need the exact count.

Also, the file *IS* open. If it wasn't there would be no way that I could output text from the text file onto the screen. Besides that, this area of the program is after checking if it is open. I did close and reopen it though so all you see is the second time it is opened. Regardless of that though, I did copy that little snippet in, and as expected, it did not say "Failed to Open" because it is open.

Comment: You have misunderstood.  If you declare `board[7][7]`, then you only get elements from 0 to 6.  Unless `BOARD_SIZE` is actually 9.  Unless you show an actual program instead of snippets, it's hard to comment on what else might be happening.  Perhaps you've redefined a variable in some scope without realising, or passed `file` into a function by value instead of reference.

Comment: Actually, my first recommendation is you actually fix the undefined behaviour.  That could be doing _anything_ to your program, including trashing stuff on the stack (such as the contents of the `file` object).  You really do have undefined behaviour.  You declared the array with square dimension `BOARD_SIZE-1` and you are accessing elements at `BOARD_SIZE-1`.  That means in memory, you're running off the end of the array by `2*BOARD_SIZE-1` bytes, thumping whatever is living there on the stack.

Comment: BOARD_SIZE = 8. That's correct. If an array is given 8 elements it would be 0 through 5. That's fine. I also tried your other snippet. The way you have it creates a compile error "array type char[7]' is not assignable." and other variations are no better.

Comment: Dude, `char chessBoards[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]`.  End of story.

Comment: I don't understand why you are obsessing over that. It make NO DIFFERENCE to use that, or an array size of a integer because that variable is just an integer constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101954/discussion-between-elliander-and-paddy).

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly if you never write `chessBoards[x][y] = point;`, you can't expect it to load the points. This applies to your first 2 snippets (which are identical). I'm assuming you accidentally copy-pasted your code twice, since they're exactly the same. It's actually pretty confusing.

Your third one has `x` and `y` as loop variables; they're out of scope by the time `chessBoards[x][y] = point;` is performed. It *looks like* you're declaring `x` and `y` twice, once near the top of this code and once in the `for`. If that's the case, you shouldn't be writing `for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)`; you probably want `for (y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++) // note the missing 'int'` instead.

The following program demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nx: " << x << ", y: " << y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
x: 0, y: 0
x: 0, y: 1
x: 1, y: 0
x: 1, y: 1

x: 0, y: 0
```

Clearly, re-declaring `x` and `y` in `for` is problematic. I'm pretty sure it's not an error because they're in different scopes, but I'm not 100% on this particular scoping rule ... mostly because what you're doing with the loop variables doesn't make sense to do in a program. If it was me, I'd probably just put `chessBoards[x][y] = point;` in the inner loop, since I think that's what you're after.

Edit to add: paddy is correct that if you want an 8-element array, you need to declare it like `array[8]`, *not* `array[7]`.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yeah, I didn't notice that it did that. I fixed the first one to show what I was doing. The point was to illustrate what I was trying to pin point the problem. I'll give your approach a try. one sec.

Comment: ok, yes,  chessBoards[x][y] = point; is supposed to be in the inner loop and  it doesn't work. The point of the other two snippets was to show what I was trying to pinpoint the problem. The second for loop, btw, works perfectly.

Comment: Does "second loop" refer to the second loop in the 1st / 2nd snippets or the only loop in the third snippet?

Comment: What happens when you declare the array properly? Also, how did the output change when you changed `x` and `y`? What's in your test file?